# null object reference

Tags: java, return, adapter

```
           Logcat

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean)' on a null object reference
```

Código do adaptador

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vista = convertView;

    if(vista==null)
        vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.elemento_lista, parent, false);

    TextView titulo = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.tvTitulo);
    TextView duracion = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.tvDuracion);
    TextView director = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.tvDirector);

    ImageView imagen = (ImageView) vista.findViewById(R.id.ivImagen);
    RatingBar calificacion = (RatingBar) vista.findViewById(R.id.ratingBarPel);

    titulo.setText(datos[i][0]);
    director.setText(datos[i][1]);
    duracion.setText("Duração " + datos[i][2]);
    imagen.setImageResource(datosImg[i]);
    calificacion.setProgress(Integer.valueOf(datos[i][3]));

    return vista;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tem que instanciar o `inflater`. Tente encaixar essa linha no começo do método `getView()`:

```
inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
```

Precisará arranjar um substituto para a variável `activity` que traga efetivamente a Activity, talvez passando como argumento no construtor do seu adaptador. Infelizmente não lembro direito como se faz isso em Android. Boa sorte.